# How can I use rake to create databases when multiple databases exist within the database.yml config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

How can I format the `rake db:create:all RAILS_ENV=development` command in a way that will capture all databases in my config file?

```
# config/database.yml
db1:
  development:
    adapter: mysql2
    host: 127.0.0.1
    database: db1
    username: user
    password: pass
  test:
    .
    .
db2:
  development:
    adapter: mysql2
    host: 127.0.0.1
    database: db2
    username: user
    password: pass
  test:
    .
    .
db3:
  development:
    adapter: mysql2
    host: 127.0.0.1
    database: db3
    username: user
    password: pass
  test:
    .
    .
```

When using `rake db:create:all` I am expecting for all of the databases (db1, db2, db3) to be created, but only db1 is created.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple database support will be a new feature in Rails 6, which is not released yet. See https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/1/18/Rails-6-0-Action-Mailbox-Action-Text-Multiple-DBs-Parallel-Testing/

The YAML structure in `database.yml` would look a little different from yours - see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33877#issuecomment-422150252

Answer (score 0):

For rails6, you can provide more than one connections and specify databases for each connection, 
eg:- database.yml

```
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: username
  password: password
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: database1
    adapter: postgresql
  secondary:
    <<: *default
    database: database2
    adapter: postgresql
```

You can do `rails db:create` for creating both database1 and database2

You can do `rails db:create:primary` for creating only database1(since it comes under primary connection).